# SBT in Apache-Spark graph frames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, graphframes

I have following SBT file, I am compiling the Scala Code using Apache GraphFrame and also reading the CSV file.

```
name := "Simple"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1",

"graphframes" % "graphframes" % "0.2.0-spark1.6-s_2.10",

"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.0.0",

"com.databricks" % "spark-csv" % "1.0.3"
)
```

Here is My Code in Scala

```
import org.graphframes._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    val nodesList = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/Users/Desktop/GraphFrame/NodesList.csv")
    val edgesList= sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/Users/Desktop/GraphFrame/EdgesList.csv")
    val v=nodesList.toDF("id", "name")
    val e=edgesList.toDF("src", "dst", "dist")
    val g = GraphFrame(v, e)
```

When I try to make the Jar file using SBT, It gives me following error during compiling

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: graphframes#graphframes;0.2.0-spark1.6-s_2.10: not found
[error] Total time:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GraphFrames are not in Maven Central repository yet.

You can:

1. download artifact on [Spark Packages](https://spark-packages.org/package/graphframes/graphframes) page and install into local repository
2. Add [Spark Packages repository](https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/) into your SBT `build.sbt`:

Code in build.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("SparkPackages", url("https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"))
```

Comment: Above code is working fine but Now I have same issue for "import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame" 
Error
"unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.10_2.10;1.0.0: not found" @T. Gawęda

Comment: @Aroon You've got strange Spark SQL version - "1.0.0" - while Spark Core is 1.6.1. Please change Spark SQL version also to 1.6.1

Comment: @Aroon also doubled version of Scala version suggest that you've changed it to `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.0.0",`. Please use %% or add Scala version. So: `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.1",` or `"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.1",`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It seems that the package DOES exist on maven. But SBT is unable to resolve it for whatever reason.
httpsunresolved dependency: graphframes#graphframes;0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11: not found

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, Resolver.url mentioned in Gawęda's answer was not working for me, the below worked:

`resolvers += "SparkPackages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"`

`libraryDependencies += "graphframes" % "graphframes" % "0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11"`

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working using [sbt-spark-package](https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package)

In `project/plugins.sbt`, I added:

```
resolvers += "bintray-spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"

addSbtPlugin("org.spark-packages" % "sbt-spark-package" % "0.2.5")
```

Then, in `build.sbt` I added:

```
spDependencies += "graphframes/graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11"
```

And it worked.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works for me. Just note that if you're going to use the `sbt-spark-package`, then make sure you use `sbt 0.13.16`, as that package does not work with `sbt 1.1.1` (see https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package/issues/35)